# MongoDB return only nested array of objects

Tags: mongodb

I have such a document:

```
   {
      "locale":"en",
      "translations":[
         {
            "name":"translation1",
            "value":"enValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation2",
            "value":"enValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation3",
            "value":"enValue"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "locale":"ru",
      "translations":[
         {
            "name":"translation1",
            "value":"ruValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation2",
            "value":"ruValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation3",
            "value":"ruValue"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

and I need for example return all translations for locale `en`, but I need to get the only an array of translations, so the result should be like:

```
[
         {
            "name":"translation1",
            "value":"enValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation2",
            "value":"enValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation3",
            "value":"enValue"
         }
      ]
```

doing `db.test.find({locale: 'en'})` result is:

```
      "_id" : "1"
      "locale": en,
      "translations" : [
         {
            "name":"translation1",
            "value":"enValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation2",
            "value":"enValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation3",
            "value":"enValue"
         }
      ]
```

but I do not want to return locale/id information just all the translations. I know there is `$elemMatch`  but it only works if I want to return a single element, for example, translation with a concrete name. How can I return the whole subset of translations without extra data??? Sorry if a question is stupid, I'm only learning mongo

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$unwind` and `$replaceRoot`

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "locale": "en" }},
  { "$unwind": "$translations" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$translations" } }
])
```